# Copy files from a folder of SD card into another folder of SD card

Tags: android, copy, directory, android-sdcard, android-file

Is it possible to copy a folder present in sdcard to another folder present the same sdcard programmatically ??

If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

An improved version of that example:

```
// If targetLocation does not exist, it will be created.
public void copyDirectory(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation)
throws IOException {

    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists() && !targetLocation.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot create dir " + targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
        File directory = targetLocation.getParentFile();
        if (directory != null && !directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot create dir " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Got some better error handling and better handles if the passed target file lies in a directory that does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

yes it is possible and im using below method in my code . Hope use full to you:-

```
public static void copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation)
        throws IOException {

    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceLocation.listFiles().length; i++) {

            copyDirectoryOneLocationToAnotherLocation(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                    new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } else {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To move files or directories, you can use `File.renameTo(String path)` function

```
File oldFile = new File (oldFilePath);
oldFile.renameTo(newFilePath);
```

Comment: This will remove file from source directory.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin code

```
fun File.copyFileTo(file: File) {
    inputStream().use { input ->
        file.outputStream().use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}

fun File.copyDirTo(dir: File) {
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs()
    }
    listFiles()?.forEach {
        if (it.isDirectory) {
            it.copyDirTo(File(dir, it.name))
        } else {
            it.copyFileTo(File(dir, it.name))
        }
    }
}
```