# How to copy image from gallery folder to any folder in sd card?

Tags: android, image, copy, android-sdcard

How to copy an image that exists in /sdcard/DCIM/ to another folder /sdcard/Photos/. How to proceed on this,please suggest a way.Thanks a many.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715104/copy-files-from-a-folder-of-sd-card-into-another-folder-of-sd-card

Comment: Thanks Kartik I tried it but it didn't come well.

Comment: Can you please paste your code here so that we can analyze where the problem lies...

Answer (score 0):

if you want only the images from DCIM the you can getExternalStorageDir()+"/DCIM/"
but this will not be recommended way...
better you can get all the images in your mobile from querying Media uri.
Check for the path if its not equal to the path of your folder than copy the image.
for copying you can do simple write operation ..
from Media you'll get the image as Bitmap then you can write it anywhere in file as byte stream.